# Compile and Link Fortran and C mac

Tags: c, fortran

Here is my C program (c_routine.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fortfunc_(int *ii, float *ff);

int main()
{
   int ii           = 5;
   float ff         = 5.5;

   fortfunc_(&ii, &ff);

   return 0;
}
```

Here is my Fortran Subroutine (fortran_routine.c):

```
subroutine fortfunc(ii,ff)
     integer ii
     real*4  ff

     write(6,100) ii, ff
100  format('ii=',i2,' ff=',f6.3)

     return
end
```

My compilation steps:

```
gfortran -c fortran_routine.f90 -o fortran_routine -ld
gcc -c c_routine.c
gcc -o test fortran_routine.o c_routine.o -ld
```

The last step though gives me the error:

```
ld: library not found for -ld
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is this an error with -ld?

Comment: I also tried gcc -o test fortran_routine.o c_routine.o -lgfortran

Comment: Try linking with gfortran instead of gcc or use the -lgfortran flag to link with the Fortran library.

Comment: It works well for me with `-lgfortran` at link time.

Comment: Thanks all. Linking with gfortran instead worked. I think that my symlinks to the gfortran libraries are busted.